# painting a button in winform panel while the panel is scrolled

Tags: c#, winforms, scroll, panel

In a panel i draw controls such as button/textbox positioned starting (0,0) in the panel. These controls are invisible and disabled at the start. I have a button outside the panel that makes these buttons/textbox visible when pressed and position them to a new location in the panel.

The problem is if user scrolled the panel to some (x,y) and then press the 'make visible' button the new (x,y) location of the button is calculated from the current (x,y) location of the panel - not from the top (0,0) of the panel.

I am wondering if this is the correct behavior of panel and that to fix this i need to consider the `this.VerticalScroll.Value` as an (x,y) offset when i re-position the buttons.

[image]

Comment: You'll need to use the panel's AutoScrollPosition property to adjust the button's Location.

Comment: Picture illustrations would help showing expected and current behavior.

Comment: i have a picture but was not able to post it...need more reputation on SO. @HansPassant From MSDN AutoScrollPosition looks like what i needed.myButton.Location = new Point(
      0 + panel1.AutoScrollPosition.X, 
      0 + panel1.AutoScrollPosition.Y);

Comment: @Neolisk The 0s in the above code is the position of the button i want draw?

Comment: @user66896: post a link to it, I'll edit to be a picture.

Comment: @Neolisk [link](http://img443.imageshack.us/img443/831/90403702.jpg)

Comment: @user66896: updated your question.

Comment: It does not seem that panel control is intended for scrolling, even though it may have some properties related to this function. I might be wrong about that, but so far it looks like your (x,y) is actually (0,0) and your (0,0) is some (0,-100), in which case everything is working as it should. What are you trying to accomplish in the end? If you explain your original intent, we could help you better.

Comment: @Neolisk When i give a position for my buttons i want them to possition relative to the panels (0,0) in the picture. Currently its positioning relative to some (x,y) in the picture.(it is considering that scrolled (x,y) value as (0,0) and positioning the buttons from there. The AutoScrollPosition did not help by the way.

Comment: @user66896: please explain what are those two rectangles. Are those two panels, one inside of another? If yes, why are you pursuing this design?

Comment: @Neolisk the green is panel. The blue within the green box is the viewable section of the panel. The blue part outside the green box is the part of the panel you need to scroll to view. I am trying to add the button relative to the (0,0). Currently its adding it relative to the scrolled, viewable section of the panel (x,y).

Comment: @user66896: thank you for clarification - I was able to reproduce the issue. Interesting... If anyone wants to try, here is link to [my project on Mediafire](http://www.mediafire.com/?a6u266sqe6bk9n6). Even though it's on VB, not C# as OP's question, it proves the concept.

Comment: What @HansPassant said actually resolved the issue. Once scrolled to get the position respect to (0,0) the (x,y) values need to adjusted using `AutoScrollPosition`.  this has to occur before paint event is called. Thank you everyone and Hans. i was testing wrong earlier.

Answer (score 2):

This is what worked for me.
When you get the Y of you button/textbox etc do:

`relativeControlTop = theControl.Top - thePanel.AutoScrollPosition.Y;`

When you set the top do:

`relativeControlTop = theControl.Top + thePanel.AutoScrollPosition.Y;`

Hope this Helps.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it would help in your situation, but I think it's worth trying:

> If you were to design the Panel using Visual Designer, I recommend
>   **using two Panels**: a full-size one holding all the Controls, its size
>   allows for easy designing; and the smaller one which has the intended
>   physical size. Then simply add the large one as the only child of the
>   smaller one (like innerPanel in bottomPanel).

See this article [Article: WinForms AutoScroll Experiment](http://www.perceler.com/articles1.php?art=autoscroll1) for more details.